# Could not ctl.interface_start 'android.hardware.configstore@1.0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs/default' for ctl.interface_start

Tags: android, android-source, android-x86

Boot animation is not starting and entering into console mode. While checking kernel logs(dmesg) getting above error.

**Observation**: Even if I changed version from 1.0 to 1.1 of this hal into **manifest.xml** still gets above error

Developing Android emulator which is based on Android X86 project.
Android version 10(Q)

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you change the configstore HAL or the init process? Please add more logs.

Comment: Thank you for reply. There is no modification in configstore HAL. But changed into init process. Actually, from P to Q partition got changed to accommodate those changed copied some partition from root to android. There is no adb connection stablished so I can't share logs if you need I can attach screenshots